# Finding USB ethernet link-local IP address in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi, ip, command-prompt

So I have a raspberry pi and another device which I am using ethernet over USB to connect to via ssh and I can not find a way to find the link-local IP address

for example if I have bonjour and putty, then `raspberrypi.local` will connect me to the pi I have hooked up. There using `ifconfig` I see the device is on `169.254.x.x` and can use that address to ssh into it as well.

I would like to be able to find that link local IP address via Windows command prompt (or PowerShell/GUI if anything) to get access to my other device by seeing its IP as well

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, than I don't think it is not out-of-the-box what you want to achieve. As far as I understand Bonjour creates the local host entry with a proprietary discovery protocol (server-client agreement between your PC and the RPi); so you would need to do something similar (e.g., scanning the available IP range, which is not the best idea ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found if you go `ipconfig /all` and find the ethernet-usb adapter it will have it under `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.xxx.xxx(Preferred)`

It will be found under a `Ethernet adapter Ethernet x:` where `x` is the number of the adapter your USB is using